# How can I navigate to any of the classes' code shown in a class diagram?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-diagram

I am looking at my class diagram, I see a class from a project-referenced assembly C (not a referenced DLL) but double-clicking it won't travel to its code nor is there a context-menu option "View Code"
How can I fix this?  Am I missing something?

Why is there no "View Code" option in Class Diagrams for classes from referenced assembly/projects?

It does not matter whether the class diagram is the main app project A or in project-referenced assembly B 
Both A/bin/debug and B/bin/debug have C.dll, C.dll.mdb and C.pdb

If it is any help, I am able to trace-thru this referenced project's C code during debug, so I am not sure if Options/Debug like / Just my code... / and such apply here.

Thanks for any pointers, this has been a frustration for quite some time both in VS2010 and now in VS2013, so I am posting...

the snapshot below relates to the comments/findings I added below.  It does not apply to the case when some of the classes in the diagram are outside of the project but still inside the solution.

[image]

Comment: I discovered somewhat by chance on project where I decided to work temporarily under Windows to develop the data layers from an Android project, that when the class diagram file is linked in the same folder along with all the linked files some of which are in this diagram.  Now clicking on the diagram navigates magically to the code.
Whats funny is that the LINKED folder I made within the Windows.Forms application is completely empty.
I made it and linked the files from the Android development to make it clear these are linked.  "linked" here means "Add as Link" feature of Visual Studio.

Comment: So I am finding it to work nicely from the DEVEL/TESTER Window.Forms project where the class diagram is linked and not existent in its physical folder structure. VS2013 resolves the location of the classes and navigates to the code.  I like working like this where I switch to the UML model and from it jump to the class/methods I want to edit/add etc...  I am commenting here on my findings, but they are not a solution. :(

Comment: Further experimentation shows the linked class diagram works navigating to code because it happen to be in the same project along with the classes it references.  It does not matter if the class diagram is at the LINKED folder with the sources files or at the root the project. And probably it might work if included instead of linked as well.
The limitation remains if the classes are inside the solution but outside of the project the class diagram can NOT navigate to them :(